# How to access the queue buffer of a node in Contiki-OS?

Tags: c, embedded, iot, contiki

I am working on a scenario where a single node is a bottle neck. Many other nodes are forwarding via this node, and i would like to check the queue buffer - where packets are stored before they are processed / forwarded- regularly. But i can not find the exact routine where multiple packets are stored in a buffer in the node before processing.

I have checked packetbuf.c, queuebuf.c files. At this point i am not even sure if Queuebuf is used to store IPv6 packets anymore.

Comment: The API for queue buffer is defined in `core/net/queuebuf.h` in Contiki, are you looking for something in particular?

Comment: I want to know where exactly the incoming IPv6 packets are stored before they are sent to queuebuf to be processed. Since queuebuf can handle only one packet at a time, i want to know how many packets are stored and buffered and are still waiting to be processed by queuebuf.

Comment: `QUEUEBUF_NUM - queuebuf_numfree()` should give you the number of packets currently in the queue buffer.

Comment: Apparently,  Queuebuf is used only for traffic generated by node x. But if node x itself is not generating any traffic, but forwarding and routing traffic for other nodes, where does node x store store incoming packets before it can process and route them?

Comment: There is one packet "stored" in the packetbuf, and up to `QUEUEBUF_NUM` packets in the queue buffer. Some protocols store their own metadata in their own structures, but the contents of the packets are in the queue buffer.